# Updating div without reloading page

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and jQuery and I need some help.

I have a form to send information and save into my database and I have a div like a table to show data. The div is like this:

```
<div id="mensagens">
    <?php
        $query = mysql_query("select * FROM tabelanova");
        while($mensagem = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
            echo "<strong>" . $mensagem->nome . "</strong> disse: <em>" . $mensagem->mensagem . "</em><br />";
        }
    ?>
```

I need it to update itself when new data is added into that table without refreshing the whole page. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the examples here: http://api.jquery.com/html/